# Do minimal proofs exist?

Tags: proof-theory

The same way that we have minimal elements in sets, are there minimal proofs in the set of all proofs of a particular problem?

Comment: You again ask a little weird question: **define** what is *a minimal proof* in the set of all proofs for a certain problem, please.

Comment: A proof where you can't remove anything.

Comment: @Jordi What do you mean by "remove" and what do you mean by "anything"?

Comment: One can define length of a proof by the number of bytes of the TeX file needed to write it up. As the length is a positive integer possible to define minimal proofs. The problem would be a proof assuming  and quoting a result and hence shorter will it be considered as really shorter than a proof that assumes nothing.  This enters the realm of subjectivity.

Comment: Well, yes: consider a fixed logic-deductive system and the set of finite strings which represent a proof of your desired (provable) theorem. Some of them will have a minimal number of characters/something else. Whether said proofs are human-friendly is debatable.

Comment: The measure I take for proofs is the number of statements. Charactares, tex bytes or whatever representation used are not relevant.

Comment: @Jordi Could you give an example of such a minimal proof according to **your** definition, please? I bet that whatever you come up with, *something is going to be removable*

Comment: @DonAntonio Let's choose any logic and try to prove that the true statement is true. This would be my proof: Trivial. Anything removable?

Comment: If your measure of proof size is a natural number then, provided that there is a proof, there must be a minimal one (not necessarily unique).  However, I would expect that for most interesting theorems, this is not known.

Comment: @Jordi Sorry, I just can't understand what you wrote: Is the statement : "The (perhaps *a*...?) true statement is true", and then your proof is... **what** ?

Comment: One way to define it would be to say that a proof is a Gentzen-style tree, and that its length is the number of nodes in the tree. Then if a formula is a theorem, it has a proof and therefore the set $\{n \mid $ there exists a proof of length $n$ of said formula$\}$ would be non empty, and thus have a minimal element. With such a minimal element comes a minimal proof. I don't see what's bothering you all. Obviously the choice of the deduction system (Gentzen type, or anything else) is subjective, but once you have (sensibly) defined what you call a proof, this becomes a mathematical problem.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, makes no sense what I said. Have to find another example.

Comment: @Jordi Ok, take your time.

Comment: Related: [Gödel's 1936 Speed-up Theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel/#SpeUpThe) and Samuel Buss, [On Gödel's theorems on lengths of proofs: Number of lines and speedup for arithmetics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/on-godels-theorems-on-lengths-of-proofs-i-number-of-lines-and-speedup-for-arithmetics/42EDBDDF8DF9FA1B3A3294AAF02CCE1A) (1994).

Comment: What is the minimal element of the set $\left\{\square, \circ , 1 , :), \text{ Hello World!} \right\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This was studied by Chaitin in his seminal paper *[Information-Theoretic Limitations of Formal Systems](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~chaitin/acm74.pdf)*.

Comment: I'm guessing, though, that minimality is uncomputable at best...